# Adding Timestamp Value in MS Access DB (MDB) using java JDBC

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am trying to insert new row in the table which has the Timestamp as Column value.
Following is my Code:

```
long millisecs = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
Timestamp ts = new java.sql.Timestamp(millisecs) ;
s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tblPublicHols(Date) VALUES("+ts+")");
```

I also tried to do it with PreparedStatment as follows:

```
long millisecs = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
Timestamp ts = new java.sql.Timestamp(millisecs) ;
PreparedStatement pstmt ;
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tblBasicHoliday " +
                 "(Date, RegionID) " +
                 "VALUES (?, ?)") ;
pstmt.clearParameters() ;
pstmt.setTimestamp(1, ts);
pstmt.setInt(2, 1);
int count = 0 ;
count = pstmt.executeUpdate() ;
```

Still I am getting same error, which as follows

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

Can anyone help me out on this?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you get the same error in both cases? (You should *definitely* use the prepared statement approach, btw.)

Comment: Yes the error is same in both the cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the problem is that `Date` is a reserved word. Try:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblBasicHoliday ([Date], RegionID) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

(Note that you should be closing the statement in a `finally` block, too.)

Comment: One more point, this is only working with PreparedStatement cant excute with statement.

Comment: @user1614217: You should be using the PreparedStatement version anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `DATE` is a [reserved word in MS Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335).  You should to change the column name and the SQL statement to use another column name that isn't a reserved word to avoid this error.

Comment: You are right, but in this case DB design is not in my control so needs to manage. But your point was exactly right. Thanks